# Set background image behind 2 text views in Android XML file

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-relativelayout

If you have any knowledge of XML layouts in Android, please take a quick look.  I have the following XML layout that displays an image, then displays an address and phone number below it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:background="@drawable/mainbackground"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" 
          android:id="@+id/view1">
   <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50px"
    android:padding="12dip"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
  </ImageView>
  <TextView android:id="@+id/addressView" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20px"
        android:padding="12dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
   </TextView>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/phoneView"
        android:textColor="#0000FF" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/addressView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="12dip"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Currently, I am just using the android:padding and android:background tags to set a white background behind the ImageView and both TextViews.  This works fine for me for the image view.  For the text views, they obviously have 2 individual borders/backgrounds.  However, I would like to set one white background image behind both text views instead of having two individual borders/backgrounds.  See this image for more details on what I would like the final result to look like:

http://img84.imageshack.us/i/homeview.png/

I am just not sure how to "wrap" this white box around both text views.  Obviously, the android:padding and android:background tags might not be the way to do this.  If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the image as a background for a LinearLayout that contains both TextViews and you are set.

Comment: Thank you for your post! I have changed my layout to a LinearLayout, and have been trying a few things, but am still in the same spot that I was before.  Could you possibly provide more details, or an example of what you mean (based on my code)?

Comment: Nevermind, I read your comment wrong.. I thought you meant to change my entire layout to a LinearLayout. I got it now! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/view1">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_marginTop="50px"
               android:padding="12dip"
               android:background="#FFFFFF">
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="commonBackgroundImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20px"
            android:padding="12dip"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/addressView"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#000000"
                  android:text="text1">
        </TextView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/phoneView"
                  android:textColor="#0000FF"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:text="text2">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```